# pip install pyautogui says the same thing over and over again

Tags: python, pycharm, pyautogui

Im very new to python and I dont know why when I type `pip install pyautogui` it says the same thing [This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yEAd.png)

Comment: Well, the picture says you're trying to `pip uninstall pyautogui` but if you're still getting the same error when installing maybe your datetime.py file is missing some data, I'd try reinstalling your current python (or maybe update to python3.9)

Comment: Which version of pip you're running ( `pip --version` )? You could try upgrading it, if it's outdated ( `pip install --upgrade pip`)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).